# Safari 8: client-side download?

Tags: javascript, safari

Is there a working method that can cause Safari 8.0.8+ (OSX 10.10.5+) to force a file to download, rather than opening it in a new tab (or more often than not, do nothing at all). I've tried the following libraries and snippets (some referenced by many SO articles):

- http://davidwalsh.name/downloadify
- https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/
- http:// codepen.io /davidelrizzo/pen/cxsGb
- http://danml.com/download.html
- https://github.com/dcneiner/downloadify
- http:// jsfiddle.net /koldev/cw7w5/